# Help me to solve this. Efforts written in photo.

Tags: logarithms

If 
$$ 2^{\log5} × 5^{\log2}= 2^{\log x} $$
Find
$$ \log_5 {x^{2/3}} $$

Here my efforts in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. If you type up the equations in MathJax you can do away with that naff photo and your question will be searchable.  Also, if you put what you have tried and where you are stuck others might see the effort you've made and be more willing to put some in themselves to help you.

Comment: When you write $\log$ with no base, does that indicate a base-$10$ logarithm?

Comment: yes it indicates base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$.

---

From my hint, you have

$$2^{\log5}\cdot5^{\log2}=2^{\log x}$$

$$2^{\log5}\cdot2^{\log5}=2^{\log x}$$

This gives

$$2\log5=\log x$$

Thus

$$x=25$$

Substitution gives

$$\log_525^{\frac23}=\frac43$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\log _5(x^{\frac{2}{3}} )=\frac{2}{3}\log _5 (x)$$
because assuming $x>0$, $\log _a\left(x^b\right)=b\cdot \log _a\left(x\right)$.

$$2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}=2^{\log _{10}\left(x\right)}$$

$$\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)=\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)=\log _{10}\left(x\right)\ln \left(2\right) \rightarrow \log _{10}\left(x\right)\ln \left(2\right)=\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)$$

Hence

$$\log _{10}\left(x\right)=\frac{\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)}{\ln \left(2\right)}=\log _{10}\left(10^{\frac{\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot \:5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)}{\ln \left(2\right)}}\right) \Longrightarrow $$$$x=10^{\dfrac{\ln \left(2^{\log _{10}\left(5\right)}\cdot 5^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}\right)}{\ln \left(2\right)}}$$